# Aggregator module - entityref error

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am working on a RSS feed. I use Aggregator module for RSS. I have source feed to import using following url:

```
http://koha.library.tu.ac.th/cgi-bin/koha/opac-search.pl?&limit=branch%253ATULAMPANG&count=50&sort_by=acqdate_dsc&format=rss2
```

But I am getting error EntityRef Error

```
"DOMDocument cannot parse XML: EntityRef: expecting ';'"
```

I have also tried changing `&` in url to `&amp;`
But still have same error.

Can anybody help me how can I fix this problem

Thank You.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is related to your specific RSS feed,  if you can share the ACTUAL URL it might help someone do a real test and find your problem

Comment: @GiorgosK I have updated the question, please help.

Answer (score 1):

The rss feed [does not seem to validate](https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fkoha.library.tu.ac.th%2Fcgi-bin%2Fkoha%2Fopac-search.pl%3F%26limit%3Dbranch%25253ATULAMPANG%26count%3D50%26sort_by%3Dacqdate_dsc%26format%3Drss2)

Also it does not seem to comform to the [RSS2 standards](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html)

The RSS2 standard proposes that each individual item to be wrapped around `<item>` tag inside `<channel>` tag but there is none in the document.

I suspect that is the reason the parser cannot parse the document.  Try with a different RSS and you will see that the parser will not have any problems.